# WCF or other technologies for load balancing

Tags: load-balancing

I would like to write an upload system (photos, videos,...), which could be scaled and perform well even under heavy traffic.
I am a .Net developer therefore I am more interested in using .Net technologies to achieve this. But I am also open to other technologies that I could use for this project.

I am also thinking about Azure OS from Microsoft, If I use Azure then I probably would not need to be worried about anything, right ? it will scale itself automatically and I probably would not need to program that part, but its closed source and they can raise the prize at any time.

I am absolutely new to load balancing therefore I don't know where to start? I need to decide a system like www.flickr.com

Any ideas folks ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a messaging queue like MSMQ.